# how to label multiple columns effectively using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data columns look like below

```
a b c d e
1 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

For this dataframe I want to create a column called label

```
    a b c d e lable
    1 0 0 0 0  cola
    0 2 0 0 0  colb
    3 0 0 0 0  cola
    0 0 0 1 0  cold
    0 0 1 0 0  colc
    0 0 0 0 1  cole
```

The label is the column index

my prior code is `df['label'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x!=0)` but it doesn't work. Is there anyway to return the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Try `idxmax` on axis 1

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
 'b': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'c': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 'd': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 'e': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]})

df['label'] = 'col'+df.idxmax(1)
```

Output

```
   a  b  c  d  e label
0  1  0  0  0  0  cola
1  0  2  0  0  0  colb
2  3  0  0  0  0  cola
3  0  0  0  1  0  cold
4  0  0  1  0  0  colc
5  0  0  0  0  1  cole
```

Comment: Is it possible to return column index like 1, 2, 3, 4,5?

Comment: I'd go ahead and rename the columns intermediately `df.rename(columns={c:i for i,c in enumerate(df,1)}).idxmax(1)` .. otherwise (this is imo horrible), you could transpose and drop the column names `df.T.reset_index(drop=True).idxmax(0) + 1`